# OpenShift Deployment is require data protect on my Application .NET 7

Tags: c#, docker, openshift, .net-7.0

I'm trying to do the deployment about my application on OpenShift but the following error on POD is showing:

[issue OpenShift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7u5V.png)

Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
Storing keys in a directory '/opt/app-root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.

Someone could help on this?

I just try to add this command line but did not work:

builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
.SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. Please keep in mind that all questions on Stack Overflow must be programming-related. As such, the question seems off-topic here. It might be on-topic for [devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). Please  consult [devops' on-topic site](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there.